# Cant find why some small images are taking 10 seconds to load

Tags: performance, magento, yslow, pagespeed

I am trying to optimize my site to accomplish at least 90 on YSlow and PageSpeed.
I am doing pretty well. But in the following result, there are 4 images that show that take 9-10 seconds to load.  If you see the detail, it actually shows that of those 10 seconds, mostluy 99% is while connecting only.

This is a magento store, and I am not sure what I should do to fix this problem because the images are not really big.
http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.theprinterdepo.com/FyZjLbUX

[image]

Thank you

Comment: You question lacks the details people would need to help you diagnose why a programmatically served/generated image might be taking longer than normal to load/be-served.

Comment: what more details do you need? its just plain html that I didnt want to paste here because maybe its not relevant.  It seems a hard question to answer.

Comment: you missed to describe what images exactly so others could actually measure the speed and see where they origin, what headers are involved, that's what Alan meant with lack of detail.

Comment: I just pasted the results and you can see clearly the images with the green bar that are taking that long. Those images are so small that I just cant find an explanation for those 9-10 seconds.  Thanks @Anton S

Comment: Do the images load that slowly in isolation?

Comment: Nop, if you copy the url and load them in a separate browser they load very fast.

Comment: What if you load them in the same browser?  There might be some session related task that triggers during the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, even [WebPageTest.org shows the same issues](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/111103_SJ_22FBT/1/details/), but there's nothing obvious as to why this occuring (at least to me), but I can make some guesses:

- you're calling an image from within the .css file on www.printerdepot.net to an image on www.printerdepot.com? (additional DNS lookup)? Sharding issue?
- but then why does it only affect some images?
- a bunch of other [possibly related issues](http://173-203-64-171.static.cloud-ips.com/scan-files/free/49ee1f743a8262d82f39aa38115fe629/report.html) that are cascading through?

I'd suggest trialling converting them to Base64 Data URIs and updating the CSS to see if that improves the performance. [See this article for more](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/).

Answer (score -2):

instead of having small images why don't you have only one image sprite? It will be much faster (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) and you will only need to send to the client one image

Comment: thats something I have in mind to do but with small pictures, as far as I know the best practice is to do it with small pictures, but if you see the image, some of the problematic images are the banners, which are big pictures in dimensions but not in size.